# Swift - notification observer is called several times

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have viewController and inside in viewDidLoad I have

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showNextQuestions", name: "showNextQuestionsID", object: nil)
```

In another controller I have

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showNextQuestionsID", object: nil)
```

If I go home from app and launch it again function showNextQuestionID fires two times.

I tried to use

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "showNextQuestionsID", object: nil)
}
```

But this doesn't help,

and in viewController

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing your notification observer in the right place. You register the observer in your view controller subclass, and you need to remove it in the same class. A logical place is to override the viewWillDisappear method. Place the following code in your view controller subclass:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Also remove

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "showNextQuestionsID", object: nil)
```

From your AppDelegate. When you supply the 'self' argument in the AppDelegate, it is referring to the AppDelegate class, not your view controller. When you call to remove your notification observer in the view controller sublcass, self is your view controller, which is what you want.

Last, when you call simply removeObserver(self) with no other arguments, it will unregister all the observers for that object. That way you don't have to go through and list each observer by name.

Comment: is there another way which is not viewWillDisappear? i need to change UI in ViewController where is observer is registered while user on another controller. Controller must be changed before user arrives here

Answer (score 0):

Put your observers in AppDelegate or a singleton, so that you can easily add and remove an observer during application states.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidEnterBackground` and `deinit` should be ok.

The problem is the way you are trying to remove the observer in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. You are trying to remove the observer from AppDelegate and you need to remove the observer from your ViewController.

To fix the problem:

1) Listen for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in your view controller:

```
func init() {
  super.init()

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "myAppDidEnterBackground", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil) 
}
```

2) Implement the method that listen to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

```
func myAppDidEnterBackground() {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "showNextQuestionsID", object: nil)
}
```

3) Extra. You could also listen for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in order to add again your custom notification